# How to tell mySQL return rows in order from a sub-query?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I need the mySQL SELECT query to return the rows in a specific order based on the results of a sub-query.

I have a list of keys that are not ordered and when I do a SELECT the result set is automatically ordered.  Is is possible for the result set to be in the same order as the list provided?

Example:

```
Select * from $table 
where Id in (8,4,1,3)
```

mysql returns them in sorted order ie: 1, 3, 4, 8

Is there a way to get the result set in the same order ie: 8, 4, 1, 3?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the same list in ORDER BY (with FIELD of FIND_IN_SET function)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific order  you can use FIELD()

```
    Select * from $table 
    where Id in (8,4,1,3) 
    order by FIELD(ID, 8,4,1,3)
```